# Delay/Queue between function with animations

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

### Details

I have a function with animations inside, when clicking the button it will `.append` a `div` to the `body`. The `div` will then animate its position moving down a little bit. When another is added all of the `div`s will move down too so they will not overlap.

Now we run into the problem! When spamming the button to create the `div`s they will overlap.

How can we stop this from happening?

*Notes:*

- So only when the last function has completed all animations the next call can start
- Needs to remember and run the function how many time you clicked the button
- The function in my plugin has options that will need to be remembered (e.g the color of the background for the popup).

### What I Have Tried

The way I see it is that I would like to create a queue for how many times you click the button and release the next in line after **x** amount of time has past (enough to finish all the animations). Problem is that I cannot find a way to do this in jQuery.

- I have looked into using `.queue` in jQuery but fail to see a way
  this can help with this matter.
- I have put a `setTimeout` onto the function but this causes a delay on the click

I feel like this is something very simple but I cannot find a solution after a few hours of messing around with it myself.

### The Demo

I have created a demo for this question, my real version is a plugin so therefor is its own function. This is just a very basic version.

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  $("body").append("<div></div>");

  $($("div").get().reverse()).each(function(index) {
    $(this).animate({
      top: "+=120px"
    }, {
      duration: 600,
      queue: false
    });

    if (index >= 2) {
      // Fade out and then remove the item
      $(this).fadeOut("fast", function() {
        $(this).remove();
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 400px;
  height: 50px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Click</button>
```

[**JSFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/4zwmm20e/)

Comment: Do you want ot add animations in a queue or just not to allow new animation before previos is done?

Comment: @LazarevAlexandr I want to remember the function has been called and only start the next one after the function running before has finished (along with all of its animations).

Comment: so actually it is a queue :)

Answer (score 3):

Try this solution.... prevent animation until animate callback

```js
animated = false;
$("button").click(function() {
  if(animated)
     return false;
  else
    animated = true;
  $("body").append("<div></div>");

  $($("div").get().reverse()).each(function(index) {
    $(this).animate({
      top: "+=120px",
      duration: 600,
      queue: false
    },function(){ animated = false; });

    if (index >= 2) {
      // Fade out and then remove the item
      $(this).fadeOut("fast", function() {
        $(this).remove();
        
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 400px;
  height: 50px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Click</button>
```

This could be a starting point for manage an animation queue.

Look at this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/92tdh7nk/)

Comment: Its closer but this is just not counting the clicks you have done. I need to remember you clicked the button x amount of times and run the function that amount of times in order.

Comment: In my plugin the function has options with it so I would need to remember that too.

Answer (score 1):

Adding animations to queue:

```
var freeToAnimate = true;
var animationQueue = [];
var i = 0;
$("button").click(function () {   
    var queueLength = animationQueue.length;    
    animationQueue.push(i);
    i++;  
    if(queueLength == 0){        
        animateDivs(i-1);  
    } else {   
        return false;                  
    }
});

function animateDivs(animationIndex) {     
      if(freeToAnimate == true) {
          freeToAnimate = false;
          var divsAmount = $("div").length;
          $("body").append("<div></div>");   
          $($("div").get().reverse()).each(function(index, el) {          
              if(index >= 2) {
                  // Fade out and then remove the item
                  $(this).fadeOut( "fast", function() {
                      $(this).remove();       
                  });
              }       

              $(this).animate({
                  top: "+=120px"               
              }, 1200, function() {
                  var indx = animationQueue.indexOf(animationIndex);
                  animationQueue.splice(indx, 1);               
                  if(index == divsAmount-1 || divsAmount == 0) {                    
                      freeToAnimate = true;  
                      if(animationQueue.length != 0) {
                          animateDivs(animationIndex+1);
                      }                
                  }                 
              });         
         });       
      }          
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4zwmm20e/12/